I am getting a TypeError: an integer is required error when trying to use the setattr method
I’m getting a TypeError: an integer is required error when using setattr in the following code.
Here are the variables involved:
attr_list = ['enable_adjacent_channel', 'enable_cochannel', 'imt_link', 'is_space_to_earth', 'num_snapshots', 'output_dir', 'output_dir_prefix', 'overwrite_output', 'seed', 'system']

config = {'general': {'num_snapshots': 100, 'imt_link': 'DOWNLINK', 'system': 'FSS_SS', 'enable_cochannel': False, 'enable_adjacent_channel': True, 'seed': 101, 'overwrite_output': True}...}

self = ParametersGeneral(section_name='general', is_space_to_earth=False, num_snapshots=10000, imt_link='DOWNLINK', system='RAS', enable_cochannel=False, enable_adjacent_channel=True, seed=101, overwrite_output=True, output_dir='output', output_dir_prefix='output')

On the first iteration of the loop, I get the error. Here are the values:
attr = 'enable_adjacent_channel'
attr_val = True

The code falls into a block that attempts to set config[self.section_name][attr] = True using setattr. Although the value is already a boolean, the interpreter raises a TypeError: an integer is required. I’m not sure why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated."
for attr in attr_list:
    try:
        attr_val = getattr(self, attr)
        if isinstance(attr_val, str):
            setattr(self, attr, config[self.section_name][attr])
       *elif isinstance(attr_val, bool):
            setattr(self, attr, bool(config[self.section_name][attr]))**
        elif isinstance(attr_val, float):
            setattr(self, attr, float(config[self.section_name][attr]))
        elif isinstance(attr_val, int):
            setattr(self, attr, int(config[self.section_name][attr]))
        elif isinstance(attr_val, tuple):
            # Check if the string defines a list of floats
            try:
                param_val = config[self.section_name][attr]
                tmp_val = list(map(float, param_val.split(",")))
                setattr(self, attr, tuple(tmp_val))
            except ValueError:
                # its a regular string. Let the specific class implementation
                # do the sanity check
                print(f"ParametersBase: could not convert string to tuple \"{self.section_name}.{attr}\"")
                exit()

    except KeyError:
        print(f"ParametersBase: NOTICE! Configuration parameter \"{self.section_name}.{attr}\" is not set in configuration file. Using default value {attr_val}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Um erro desconhecido foi encontrado: {e}")


You should post the traceback in the question. The info in there is more useful than any of the words you could write.

Please post the full traceback of the error.

If you're not getting a traceback, it's because the try/except is catching the error. Remove that while debugging so you can see exactly where it's happening.

I suspect enable_adjacent_channel is a @property and it's doing this type check.

This work for me :
class ParametersGeneral:
    def __init__(self, section_name, enable_adjacent_channel=False, enable_cochannel=False, num_snapshots=10000, imt_link='DOWNLINK', system='RAS', seed=101, overwrite_output=True, is_space_to_earth=False, output_dir='output', output_dir_prefix='output'):
        self.section_name = section_name
        self.enable_adjacent_channel = enable_adjacent_channel
        self.enable_cochannel = enable_cochannel
        self.num_snapshots = num_snapshots
        self.imt_link = imt_link
        self.system = system
        self.seed = seed
        self.overwrite_output = overwrite_output
        self.output_dir = 'output'
        self.output_dir_prefix = 'output' 
        self.is_space_to_earth = is_space_to_earth
        self.output_dir = output_dir
        self.output_dir_prefix=output_dir_prefix

for attr in attr_list:
    try:
        attr_val = getattr(self, attr)
        config_value = config[self.section_name][attr]
        
        print(f"Setting attribute '{attr}' with value from config: {config_value} (type: {type(config_value)})")

        if isinstance(attr_val, str):
            setattr(self, attr, config_value)
        elif isinstance(attr_val, bool):
            setattr(self, attr, bool(config_value))
        elif isinstance(attr_val, float):
            setattr(self, attr, float(config_value))
        elif isinstance(attr_val, int):
            setattr(self, attr, int(config_value))
        elif isinstance(attr_val, tuple):
            try:
                param_val = config_value
                tmp_val = list(map(float, param_val.split(","))) 
                setattr(self, attr, tuple(tmp_val))
            except ValueError:
                print(f"ParametersBase: could not convert string to tuple \"{self.section_name}.{attr}\"")
                exit()

    except KeyError:
        print(f"ParametersBase: NOTICE! Configuration parameter \"{self.section_name}.{attr}\" is not set in configuration file. Using default value {attr_val}")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Um erro desconhecido foi encontrado: {e}")

I think the problem is related with the problem enable_adjacent_channel type.
can you share your ParametersGeneral class ?

Don't just post code. Explain what the OP did wrong and how you fixed it.
